# Using const char to organize strings

Tags: c, sorting, swap, c-strings, selection-sort

I'm trying to sort these pre-determined strings alphabetically, but my strcmp and strcpy are saying that my const char* is being violated by char* used in the functions.

Heres the code;

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 10

int main(void) {
    const char* cities[size] = { "Acushnet", "Dartmouth", "Fairhaven", 
            "Fall River", "Freetown", "Marion", 
            "Mattapoisett", "New Bedford", "Rochester", "Westport" };
    //using values a and b to hold values
    int a;
    const char b;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int a = i + 1; a <= size; a++) {
            if (strcmp(cities[i], cities[a]) > 0) {
                strcpy(b, cities[i]);
                strcpy(cities[i], cities[a]);
                strcpy(cities[a], b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `strcpy` warnings you are getting are on point.  `cities` is an array of pointers to constant strings.  Using those as as the first (destination) parameter to `strcpy` attempts to violate `const`ness.  An alternate approach would be to swap pointers rather than the strings values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` expects a `char *` for the first argument and a `const char *` for the second.  `b` is neither of these but a `const char` instead.  Also, because your array members have type `const char *`, they can't be passed as the first argument to `strcpy`.

Since you have an array of pointers, you only need to swap the pointers themselves, not what they point to.

```
        if (strcmp(cities[i], cities[a]) > 0) {
            const char *tmp = cities[i];
            cities[i] = cities[a];
            cities[a] = tmp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `b` has the type `const char`.

```
const char b;
```

So this call of the function `strcpy`

```
strcpy(b, cities[i]);
```

does not make a sense because the first argument of the function must have the type `char *`. What you need is to swap pointers that represent elements of the array of pointers.

Moreover this for loop

```
for (int a = i + 1; a <= size; a++) {
```

can result in accessing memory beyond the array `cities` when `a` is equal to `size` because the valid range of indices is `[0, size)`..

You need to declare the variable `b` as having the type `const char *` as the type of elements of the array.

```
const char *b;
```

And write the for loops at least the following way

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for ( int a = i + 1; a < size; a++) {
        if ( strcmp(cities[i], cities[a]) > 0) {
            b = cities[i];
            cities[i] = cities[a];
            cities[a] = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const char* cities[] = 
    { 
        "Acushnet", "Dartmouth", "Fairhaven", "Fall River", "Freetown", "Marion", 
        "Mattapoisett", "New Bedford", "Rochester", "Westport" 
    };
    
    const size_t size = sizeof( cities ) / sizeof( *cities );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < size; j++ )
        {
            if ( strcmp( cities[j], cities[i] ) < 0 )
            {
                const char *tmp = cities[i];
                cities[i] = cities[j];
                cities[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" ", cities[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"Acushnet" "Dartmouth" "Fairhaven" "Fall River" "Freetown" "Marion" "Mattapoisett" "New Bedford" "Rochester" "Westport"
```